# How to prevent the addition of HTML in "Full HTML" text format?

Tags: 7

Sometimes, Drupal has the annoying habit to automatically add HTML to the content's source, generally `<br/>` and `<p>`, even when the text format is set to "Full HTML".

This is really annoying and I can't find any way to prevent that.  Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found the answer:

This is a "feature" of the Full HTML mode.

> Full HTML:
>
> - Web page addresses and e-mail addresses turn into links automatically.
> - Lines and paragraphs are automatically recognized. The 
>    line break,
>
>   paragraph and
>
>   close paragraph tags are inserted
>     automatically. If paragraphs are not recognized simply add a couple
>     blank lines.

You can disable it in You are here `Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats` by unchecking `Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>)`.

Source: http://drupal.org/node/503754

Comment: My, too slow ...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the configuration of the filters the input format uses.

You can disable the tags you're talking about on the page : http://yoursite/admin/config/content/formats/full_html.

Just uncheck `Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>)`.